# Unable to make post request to Node server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cross-domain

I am building a simple server using Node JS. I am using express for routing. I wanted to test post requests using JQuery, but I have been unable to succeed. I looked up the issue and many responses mentioned a cross-origin issue. I followed every piece of advice on the subject, but I am still unable to make it work. Here is my server code:

```js
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser-json')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.base);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("ok");
});

/*Run the server.*/
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

I have tried using the core module and also manually enabling CORS. Still nothing.

Here is my front end test code:

```js
function makePost() {
    $.post( "secret.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/", { base: "Hello" })
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Got it" );
    })
    .fail(function( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Finally, here is the error I get when the post fails:

> [Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()" 
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   file:///Users/my_name/Documents/Development/Origin/FrontEndTest/jquery.js
>   :: .send :: line 4"  data: no]

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

On server you have to set response in your route methods. Otherwise client side will wait for it and finally crash.

in server file change your routes to this code:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.base);
  res.end();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("ok");
  res.end();
});
```

You can also send some response data from server, if yes, then change `res.end()` to `res.send("some response");`

Comment: I added that statement, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Is error message the same as before? In terminal where server run is message from console.log? What you get when you use browser and address server  '/'? Maybe write answers in your question (edit it)

Comment: No message on the server side, same message as before in the browser. The request isn't getting to the server. The GET request works, but the POST does not.

Comment: Try two things:
1)comment ```app.use(cors());```
2)remove ```var bodyParser = require('body-parser-json')``` and
```app.use(bodyParser.json())``` install normal body parser ```npm install --save body-parser``` and then in code write instead removed lines : ```var bodyParser = require('body-parser');```  ```app.use(bodyParser.json());``` and
  ```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));``` If something from this help, i will edit my answer and put solution there

Comment: Made all the changes, but still the same error persists.

Comment: This is going to sound stupid and I don't really understand it but prefixing http:// to the url solved the problem.